# How I can create 1000 account with batch apex?

Tags: apex, batch

How to use batch apex to create 1000 account and 10 opportunities per account..

Comment: Sush, that's a rather straight forward thing to do if you know DML and batch classes in Apex. What part is not clear to you ? The more specific your question is, the better we're able to help. If you're new to apex I'd recommend you start by just reading the [apex developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/) or having a go at the [apex workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a batch that has a query for user in the start method (LIMIT 1 as All you need is a record to be returned so the execute method is called)

then in the execute method simply:

```
Account[] a = New Account[]{};

for(Integer x=0;x<1000;x++)
  a.add(New Account(Name='Account Name'));

insert a;
```

**Although I have NO IDEA WHY you would want to do this**

Comment: Thanks Eric, but previously when I was trying to use list<Account> it's coming as double but when using Account [] it's working fine :). What is the difference between this the list and []?

Comment: Nothing is different so you must have had something else incorrect

Answer (score 3):

To append Eric's answer, if you also want 10 opportunities per account. **After Eric's code:**

```
List <Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
for (Integer x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
{
    for(Integer y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        Integer OpportunityNumber = x * 10 + y;
        String oppName = 'Opportunity Name' + OpportunityNumber;
        oppList.add(New Opportunity(Name=oppName, Account=a[x]));
    }
}
insert oppList;
```

Comment: Thanks Lance but i am getting the error, "First error: Too many DML rows: 10001"

Comment: @Sush Sorry just forgot about the limit. One simple way to avoid this is just put Eric's code and mine into two different batches. Since my code has exactly 10000 dml rows, it should resolve your issue